# Proper way to deal with empty numeric cells in a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I am reading in a CSV file from a commercial measurement processing software by writing my own CSV import method (in c# btw). The contents are a bit strange in that many intermittent empty cells occur where there should be numeric values. Like so:

> Zeit [s] ; Speed [m/s] ; Distance [m] ; X [m/s²] ; Y [m/s²] ; Z [m/s²] ; Zext [m/s²] ;
>
> 0,100000 ; 0,000000 ; 0,000000 ; 0,004023 ; 0,009220 ; -0,007959 ; 0,035353 ;
>
> 0,100167 ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; -0,021732 ;
>
> 0,100333 ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; -0,003706 ;
>
> 0,100500 ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; 0,041362 ;
>
> 0,100667 ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; 0,035353 ;
>
> 0,100833 ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; 0,044366 ;
>
> 0,101000 ; 0,000000 ; 0,000000 ; -0,003253 ; 0,000765 ; 0,003821 ; 0,008312 ;
>
> 0,101167 ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; -0,006710 ;
>
> 0,101333 ;  ;  ;  ;  ;  ; -0,027741 ;
>
> and so on...

**Is there any convention for CSV that dictates how to deal with the missing values when the respective column is numeric?**

To me it is rather obvious from the specific experimental context that the missing values should be constant (i.e. staying at the last valid value in that column), but when I am writing a general import filter for CSV, I would like to safely assume that this is **always** the case for CSV's from different sources.

And what about the time column/abscissae: if they were ever missing some values, it makes no sense to keep them constant (and since I don't know for sure that abscissae are always in the first column, I don't know what to keep constant at all!)...

Otherwise I am asking myself how a commercial package can throw out such an ill-defined rubbish of a CSV file.

**PS:** sorry if the c# tag is wrong, it's just the language I am coding in, but it has no direct relation to the question. Could be removed if not desired.

Comment: Do you _have to_ pull your own csv solution or do _want to_ write it yourself? First advice would always be "use a lib for dealing with csv".

Comment: @Fildor: True. But the problem is, it started simple, and now I am already virtually done with it. The pathologic case has occured afterwards. So if I just knew the "proper" (if any) way to do it, I could just add that to my implementation.

Comment: if `0` will interfere with further calculations in your case, you could use a `Nullable` type. Have you thought about? But on a second thought... could you show us a use case ?=! Is this supposed to be a matrix? so in each row the number of columns has to remain the same? or why do you have to treat the missing values as *something* ?

Comment: @MongZhu: I could do that, but that is merely an implementation detail. Then I am still left with the problem of how to interpret the missing values in a "standard" conformal way (again, if there is any such part of the standard).

Comment: a lot of Library has handle for default value when data are missing. But how do you wan't to handle it ? Default 0 value? Compute them based on previous data? Drop the line as not complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> by writing my own CSV import method

Don't do that? There are multiple libraries that will do that for you, each one better than whatever you would hand-code, because they have multiple man-years in experience, testing and real-world use.

> it is rather obvious from the specific experimental context that the missing values should be constant

This has nothing to do with CSV. This is your programs logic. Your data format defines that your values are missing. That is what a normal CSV reader will do for you. Your business logic *might* be that missing values will be replaced by their last known values.

So you need to place that in two different parts of your program. Data import (csv reading) and business logic.

Comment: I see, so the correct way would be to ask the user after the CSV import about how the business logic should interpret empty cells (interpolate, keep constant, or even dismiss data altogether), because it's not part of the CSV standard, right?

Comment: @oliver I guess that's up to you to figure out. It's business logic. Maybe a default is the right way, maybe it's interactively asking the user, maybe it's rejecting the file.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have the Zext accelaration (assuming it's another sensor value) that is being pulled more often than the other values.
One sixts of a milisecond, while the others are updated every milisecond.

So in order to save space, the other values are ignored, not written, to not make the CSV file grow unnecessarily.
What you have to define with yourself is which data is crucial for you?
If you're going to write the values in a relational database, it will take the space defined for the datatype, if you write in the extrapolated value (let's just say, taking the value from the previous "full line") or a zero.

So, if the Zext values are unneccessary for your thing, ignore the whole lines, otherwise you can extrapolate/copy the values from the previous full lines.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you have delimiters ";", you can split based on the delimiter. That way you can read the contents of the cells (empty or not).

Comment: Sure, but the question is: is there a default numeric interpretation of an empty cell, and if yes, which one (zero is certainly wrong in my context).

Comment: its not numeric, if you split, you get a string. An empty cell will be an empty string "". You can parse the float if the cell is not empty.